# Tweets incompletos na busca do método searchTwitter

Tags: r, twitter-api, scraping, dataframe

Olá, comunidade do Stackoverflow BR, estou brincando com a biblioteca `twitteR` da **linguagem de programação R**, e percebo que nas buscas que realizei, os **textos estão cortados**, exemplo: *"RT @fulaniinn2070 não acredito que depois de tudo que fizemos, eles ainda tiv..."*. Segue o trecho de código que estou utilizando.

```
library(twitteR)
search_twitter <- searchTwitter("#Brasil",n=1000,lang="pt-br")
search_df <- twListToDF(search_twitter)
```

Tem como eu obter o texto completo?

Comment: Essa biblioteca está depreciada, o criado sugeriu trocar pro rtweet:
https://twitter.com/geoffjentry/status/927672480185180160

Comment: @LucasMiranda obrigada, verei